# Не собирается программа в Qt при изменении статической библиотеки

Tags: windows, qtcreator

Добрый день!

Создал в **Qt Creator** статическую библиотеку и приложение. Для **Windows**.

В pro файле приложения указал

```
win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$OUT_PWD/Stat/ -lStat
```

Все хорошо слинковалось и заработало.
Однако, когда я меняю какой - нибудь исходник в библиотеке и собираю все, то библиотека компилируется, линкуется, а вот приложение не пересобирается.

Т.е. не чувствует оно, что библиотека изменилась и нужно перелинковать.
Если выбрать пункт меню "Пересобрать без зависимостей" для приложения, то все нормально слинковывается.

Как сделать так, чтобы приложение автоматически перелинковывалось при изменении библиотеки?

Comment: Ответа так и не нашел. Стал пользоваться Visual Studio.